# How to create chart from webservices in Pentaho

Tags: web-services, charts, pentaho, kettle

We have a requirement to create different charts like pie chart,line chart etc using pentaho.
We are getting data for these charts from a SOAP based webservices call.
what is the best approach.?
can we use PDI(kettle) component in Pentaho to get data from webservice and then use pentaho designer to create charts from PDI datasource?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to consume the charts? email? web? mobile? PDF?

Do you need to store the data from the soap call, e.g. to build up a history, or literally just display the chart at that point of time from the soap call?

If the former, you'll have to use PDI to get the data then store it.

If the latter then you could probably just do this directly in CDE, and build up a dashboard to show the charts. The charting in CDE / CTools is the best there is in the Pentaho stack.  If you've not heard of CDE/Ctools then check it out - it's a vital plugin for any Pentaho installation, and parts of it are included in Pentaho by default now.

Comment: Thanks.As mentioned in my query, We are getting data from webservice API.Is it possible to create charts based on webservices call in CDE tool?Please confirm.Appreciate if you can send some links/tutorials which explains in details

Comment: we wanted to consume charts in web and mobile

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would be possible - But I dont know exactly how it is done. I recommend visiting the ##pentaho IRC forum on freenode and asking there - some of the CDE/CCC developers reside there.

Answer (score 0):

Every chart is a picture generated by charting engine. Pentaho has couple of charting engines (Birt Reports, Jasper Reports). You should use the Pentaho BI, which under http normal GET request will send back the resources as requested. Just like normal web browsing, where pictures can be accessed as inner urls when page is rendered. The parameters to chart can be passes as HTTP GET/PUT parameters.